# Как мне создать полноценный модуль в c++?

Tags: c++

потребовалось сделать модуль в c++ состоящий из 2-х cpp файлов и одного h файла.
Я пытался сделать модуль самостоятельно, но мне выдавало ошибку

```
Ошибка  LNK2005 "double * w" (?w@@3PANA) уже определен в header.obj
Ошибка  LNK1169 обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более  neuro
```

Не смог разобраться с преподом по поводу того, как сделать модуль (не поняли, как пофиксить ошибку). Пишу сюда, надеюсь, что поможете.
Код ниже:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "header.h"

#define _weights 3

double w[_weights];

using namespace std;

double activation(double a)
{
    if (a <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

double process(double inputs[3])
{
    double result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        result += w[i] * inputs[i];
    }
    return result;
}

void train(int data[4][3], int exp[4])
{
    const double lr = 0.1, epochs = 100;
    double error;

    for (int i = 0; i < epochs; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            error = exp[j] - activation(process((double*)data[j]));
            for (int n = 0; n < _weights; n++)
            {
                w[n] += lr * error * data[j][n];
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    header();
    int data_train[4][3] = { {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0} }, y[4] = { 0, 1, 0, 0 };
    srand(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < _weights; i++)
    {
        w[i] = fmod(rand() % 100000000 * 0.1, 1.05);
    }
    train(data_train, y);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (w[i] > 0)
        {
            w[i] = w[i];
        }

        else
        {
            w[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    double new_[3] = { 0, 1, 0 };
    printf("%.1f", activation(process(new_)));
}
```

Код, который был в header.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _HEADER_H_
#define _HEADER_H_


#define _weights 3

double w[_weights];

void train(int data[4][3], int exp[4]);
double process(double inputs[3]);
double activation(double a);

#endif // !_HEADER_H_
```

Код, который был в header.cpp

```
using namespace std;

#define _weights 3

double w[_weights];

double activation(double a)
{
    if (a <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


double process(double inputs[3])
{
    double result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        result += w[i] * inputs[i];
    }
    return result;
}

void train(int data[4][3], int exp[4])
{
    const double lr = 0.1, epochs = 100;
    double error;

    for (int i = 0; i < epochs; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            error = exp[j] - activation(process((double*)data[j]));
            for (int n = 0; n < _weights; n++)
            {
                w[n] += lr * error * data[j][n];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код, который был в main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int data_train[4][3] = { {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0} }, y[4] = { 0, 1, 0, 0 };
    srand(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < _weights; i++)
    {
        w[i] = fmod(rand() % 100000000 * 0.1, 1.05);
    }
    train(data_train, y);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (w[i] > 0)
        {
            w[i] = w[i];
        }

        else
        {
            w[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    double new_[3] = { 0, 1, 0 };
    printf("%.1f", activation(process(new_)));
}
```

Comment: Вопрос лишь в том, что я переносил функции в header.cpp, в header.h делал заголовки, а в main.cpp запускал функцию main. Но всё равно выдавало ошибку

Comment: Гм, а что вы понимаете под "*модулем*"?

Comment: В заголовке про изготовление модулей, а в теле вопроса - про ошибку LNK2005 при сборке exe. Вам стоит определиться, что вы все-таки хотите. И если вопрос про ошибку, то следует привести [mcve]. exe не являются модулями, модули были добавлены в С++20

Comment: приведите код из "header.h" и "main.cpp". Судя по всему вы 2 раза объявляете массив `double w[_weights];`

Comment: header.h, header.cpp, в котором представлены реализации всех основных функций и main.cpp, в котором вызываются все функции из header'а

Comment: *"header.h, header.cpp, в котором представлены реализации всех основных функций и main.cpp, в котором вызываются все функции из header'а"* - никогда не пересказывайте словесно содержимое файлов, а приводите настоящий код. Телепатов тут нет.

Comment: Копипаста `double w[_weights];` в каждом файле...

Comment: @user7860670 привёл

Comment: В header.h закомментировал double w[_weights], всё равно ничего

Comment: *"закомментировал double w[_weights], всё равно ничего"* - не верю, после этого должны были появиться ошибки компиляции, так как объявление символа `w` перестало быть доступно в `main`. Короче составляйте [mcve], а не вываливайте сюда весь свой код.

Comment: В `header.h` напишите `extern double w[_weights];`. А вообще зачем вы делаете этот массив глобальным? Сделайте его локальным в `main()` и передавайте в функции также, как и другие массивы. И если уж у вас в тэгах `c++`, то вообще используйте `std::vector<>` или `std::array<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `header.h` напишите `extern double w[_weights];`. Таким образом вы делаете объявление данных, без инициализации. Эта инструкция сообщает, что где-то есть такой массив. Его линковщик соберет на своем этапе. А инициализация должна быть только одна.
А вообще зачем вы делаете этот массив глобальным? Сделайте его локальным в `main()` и передавайте в функции также, как и другие массивы. И если уж у вас в тэгах c++, то вообще используйте `std::vector<>` или `std::array<>`.
Еще несколько недочетов:
Не используйте `#define _weights 3`.

```
// не надо так
#define _weights 3
// делайте так
const int _weights = 3;
```

Одну размерность для массивов вы объявили. Так почему в функциях используете "магические" числа? И почему не объявили вторую размерность?

```
int main()
{
    int data_train[4][3] = { },  // почему не data_train[4][_weights]?
        y[4] = { };  // почему вторая размерность не объявлена?

    for (int i = 0; i < _weights; i++)  // здесь всё ОК
        w[i] = fmod(rand() % 100000000 * 0.1, 1.05);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)   // а здесь почему не i < _weights?
        if (w[i] <= 0)
            w[i] = 0;
}
double process(double inputs[3]) // а здесь почему не inputs[_weights]?
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // а здесь почему не i < _weights?
      {}
}
void train(int data[4][3], int exp[4]) // и здесь?
```

Объявление размерностей константами поможет вам не допускать ошибок с выходом за пределы массивов. Также использование контейнеров стандартной библиотеки поможет вам в этом.
А если не нравится передавать в функции много параметров, то создайте свою структуру  в которую поместите все размерности и все массивы. Создайте в main объект этой структуры и передавайте в функции по ссылке.

```
struct MyData
{
    const int _weights = 3;
    const int size = 4;
    double w[_weights];
    int data_train[size][_weights];
    int y[size];
};

double process(MyData& d, const int a)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d._weights; i++)
        result += d.w[i] * d.data_train[a][i];
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    MyData data;
    process(data, 0);
}
```